# Merge two facing pages with Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, master-page

I have such a document:

[image]

1) **How to merge each spread (two facing pages) into one big page?**
For example, how to convert pages 2-3 (each of them A4) into **a single A3 landscape page**, without having to move all the content manually?

2) When working with `Facing pages` (*File > Document setup*), is it possible to **remove the fact of having the first page alone?** i.e. I'd like first spread to be 1-2, then 3-4, 5-6. This, instead of
1 (alone), 2-3, 4-5, 6-7, etc.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... Isn't your existing answer exactly what you need to do? Why doesn't that work?

Comment: @Cai I was searching without solution during 3 hours, I posted a bounty, and 5 minutes later I found a solution (thus my answer!)

Comment: Oh right sorry, I didn't realise you posted the answer after the bounty! Well at least you found the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is finally not needed, because this feature solves everything:

*File > Export > Save as type: "Adobe PDF (Interactive)" > Export as:  "Spreads"*

[image]

Example, let's say we have an art book with some photo spread on two pages:

[image]

With this "Spreads" feature, we have a big landscape A3 page instead of two A4 portrait pages, in the final PDF:

[image]

Comment: Not exactly @Metis, in #2 you suggested to "Turn off facing pages" (or maybe I misunderstood your #2?). Here it's a bit different, it's important to keep "Facing pages" on, and then the trick is to "Export Spreads" instead of "Export Pages" in File > Export. (I spent the last three hours trying every possible trick, then I posted a bounty, ... and finally I found this!)

Comment: If your intent was to combine spreads _when exporting to PDF_, you should have made that clear. Scott’s answer is correct: there is no automated way to do what your question actually asks, which is to combine the pages _in the InDesign document_. Doing it in a PDF is a different matter, of course.

Answer (score 2):

1) There is **no automatic feature**, that I'm aware of, to "merge" pages. You have to do it manually. It's often easy to set up a neww document with pages *at* the spread size, then just copy from two pages in one document, to one page in the new document. Paste in place --- <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> --- is *sometimes* helpful with this.

2) **Turn off facing pages.** You have single pages, then you can shuffle them however you want and create your own spreads. You may need to check the `Allow Document Pages to Shuffle` Option in the the **Pages Panel**. 
<sub>(or uncheck it.. it never seems to reflect the check mark consistently here... sometimes it's checked and I can shuffle.. sometimes it's checked and I can't. Whatever state it's in... you may need to just toggle that option)</sub>

Comment: 3) select and **group** all items on each *spread*; go into document settings resize to 2x width while disabling facing pages; then clean up orphaned page front cover back cover. This can be done very quickly from 10% zoom (etc)

Comment: For 1), do we have to do this *manually* for each page / spread? I haven't found a "Select All" feature that allows to select all objects from all pages... If not 1) is not an option because there are more than 100 pages...

Answer (score -2):

I just realised that when you export you can choose to have the spread instead of singular pages which solves the problem

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In order to have a useful answer for future readers, can you edit your answer to include a screenshot?

Comment: This is exactly what an existing answer says.